# When the OP expects you to fully rewrite their entire code

Tags: discussion, answers

I've seen this situation a lot: OP posts a question with included code that has multiple parts to it. For example, excerpts of PHP, HTML, SQL. All three are important to provide context to what they're doing, but their issue only lies in one. So an answer is given, and naturally it doesn't include a copy of all the code. Instead, it only includes the parts that were problematic. For example, maybe the user had an issue only in a `for` loop in their PHP, so the answer specifies that and shows the solution, including code exclusively for that `for` loop.

The OP in return comments with something like "Where's the answer?" or "Please give me the code." In other words, the OP doesn't accept the answer not on the merit of the answer but because it requires them to do more than just copy and paste.

How should such situations be handled? At what point is it appropriate to tell the OP that we will not code for them and that they must put effort into learning? What is the most appropriate way to inform them, without coming across as rude or elitist? Cases of harassment aside, is there ever a point where a moderator should be flagged during the conversation?

Comment: Close immediately as 'too broad'.  We can't debug distributed systems by blog.

Comment: Just don't respond at all to such a comment, there is no need.  Never make yourself a hostage to an OP dangling an answer mark, you can easily outlast his need to get his job done.

Comment: Silently walk away. You don't have to respond to their comments. I've seen it a couple of times that OP asks one or two times, and if you don't answer they will start thinking themselves. Next day they usually write something like "Tahnks. I figured it out".

Comment: @MatthiasBauch That or someone else just posts an answer that is the same as your answer, but includes enough of the OP's original code to allow them to copy-paste the answer without thinking, and that answer is accepted.

Comment: "Too broad"? That doesn't sound like the right reason. On the contrary, such a question seems to be too specific. A broad question is something like, "How do I implement a CRM system in PHP?"

Comment: Never let the needy question asker bully you! After all, you are the honorable esteemed teacher! I say, simply this - only visit a question once. Your wisdom is like fragrance, you need to spread all over. Time is money

Comment: Downvote as too lazy. Refer to FAQ/how to ask etc. Close if it really is 'too broad' to be answered. Then move on and don't fret.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the least what the OP 'expects'.  It's your time. Use it as you will.

Comment: I consider comments in the context of a SO page by an answerer/asker to be part of that person's contribution to the page.  I vote accordingly.  Note this also means that often deleting the bad content will reverse my vote decisions.  Voting is cheap, and not that important, but neither is someone being lazy in comments.

Comment: "What is the most appropriate way to inform them, without coming across as rude or elitist?" If you can stand the one or other revenge down vote, be rude and elitist... some posters almost ask for it. ;-)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you've provided an answer that you consider to be sufficiently complete, but that the OP considers incomplete, you can either add the additional information or not.  You can freely choose.  If you don't want to add information that you feel is either unnecessary, or that would detract from the answer then don't.  You've posted your answer, you don't need to do anything else if you don't want to.  Other community members can indicate, through voting, whether they consider the answer incomplete or sufficiently complete.

Comment: Where's the answer? Please give me the code.

Answer (score 37):

> How should such situations be handled?

Be nice. Assume innocence before guilt. I know it can be difficult with the amount of junk that gets posted as questions, but there's an easy solution: be selective about what you answer. Stack Overflow is about quality, not rep.

> At what point is it appropriate to tell the OP that we will not code for them and that they must put effort into learning? What is the most appropriate way to inform them, without coming across as rude or elitist?

If they don't know this, they either didn't read the FAQ, or didn't understand it. Pointing them to the FAQ, along with a *polite* comment about SO not being a coding service, is probably the least patronising thing to do.

> Cases of harassment aside, is there ever a point where a moderator should be flagged during the conversation?

No; flagging is for a question with such **serious problems** that it can't be dealt with via any other route available. Some of those other routes are downvotes and close votes, which should be your first port of call (remember, downvoting a *question* doesn't take rep).

Comment: "Stack Overflow is about quality, not rep." Oh how I wish that were the case. I regularly see people answering "low hanging fruit" questions that should be voted closed for a variety of reasons. I'm assuming folks are doing that because it's an easy way to boost their rep.

Comment: @CraigW.: Some of them, doubtless, but some of them are answering because they *know the answer after five seconds of thought* and it feels wrong to deny someone in need the answer to their problem.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Difference in philosophy I suppose. I tend to come down on the "teach a man to fish" side of things. If it only took me five seconds of thought then with a little effort the OP could have come to the same conclusion rather than waiting to be spoon fed the answer.

Comment: @CraigW.: And I don't disagree with you; I'm just trying to point out that, philosophy or no, it can be hard to resist the temptation to be slightly helpful in such cases, even if one normally considers it best to promote the ability to learn rather than tutoring.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - questions that can be answered in five seconds are dupes I guarantee it! I close 40 of them every time I hit the review queue, I could close 400 of them every day and they all have half a dozen *answers" that are partial and incomplete because the gamification supports quickly posted crap answers to crap questions now. I am sure that these same posts qualify for at least 3 - 4 other legimate close reasons as well. I have seen high rep users reopen dupes just so they can answer them with the exact same answer as in the duplicate that it was closed on.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: To be honest, duping doesn't feel like a very solid match for VtC per se; it's really a special type of answer that just happens to mean that there's no point putting further answers around. What's more, dupe-hunting is one of the most tedious and least rewarding activities on SE. Not that that justifies reopening a dupe, of course.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Anyway, if absolutely all five-second answers are dupes, I would be more than surprised. A lot of them aren't dupes at all: they're typos on such a level that there's no existing question for them, or are otherwise pretty silly mistakes that just haven't come up before (in any discernible way).

Comment: @NathanTuggy - *I am sure that these same posts qualify for at least 3 - 4 other legimate close reasons as well.* There is a **Typos** close reason, use then, and "why is this code not working", "too broad" and what not exist, people just refuse to vote to close because they are rep whores, they have diluted those of us who really earned our rep with quality answers to the point I do not care. I have 34K worth of down voting answers points as I see it now.

Answer (score 17):

I've seen these go both ways. Sometimes it is the OP being difficult and expecting a complete functional rewrite, but other times its the answerer dropping what appears to be working code without explanation or context.

This can be part of the problem with code only answers, while a more experienced developer may see the new code block and know exactly what it does and where it fits in, a less experienced developer looks at it and goes "I think that looks better, but what do I do with it?"

All I'm try to say is that in some cases a little explanation goes a long way.

Something as simple as:

> On line three you have: `bar the foo`
>   It should be: `foo the bar`

Tells the OP a lot more than just

> You need to: `foo the bar`

Comment: In this case, I was specifically referring to when the OP included an explanation as well, not just `foo the bar`.

Answer (score 6):

In situations like that, I will often reply to the comment with a message explaining my answer (further) and provide details of what aspect of the problem it attempts to solve, the OP should expect that they will have to integrate the answer in to their solution.

If they raise a valid point about something I've missed then I may revisit my answer. If they persist on adding new information and effectively want the world on a stick, I'd leave my answer as it is and move on as I offered my assistance on the question that was posted.

If it turns out the question wasn't complete and you're getting drawn in to additional Q&A's in comments, you shouldn't feel under any obligation to revisit the post until it's improved, as there's a high probability that the relevant information may never turn up.

It completely up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I used to do this back in the day when I was a lot younger. (On other boards, like phpfreaks, javascript forums, etc). I believe it's a part of just growing up and a phase young `wannabe` programmers go through.

In the end though, it's about how much dedication the OP has put into their post. If they just write a 2 liner question and ask 'Please, show me how?', I think it's best to ignore the person in general. Similarly, we do this in real life as well. (Well, I do). If there are people at school who annoy, or act like  `babies`, if you will. It's just best to ignore them. I find doing that the same here or on other sites is key. You are wasting their time, and your own.

With that said, there are a couple people who do stick out in my mind that were there that helped me in rough coding times. Those people do stick out and I commend them for putting up with me and I'm sure they know they have my gratitude..

But always show professionalism and be courteous to them no matter what. There is no room for hostility on the internet. My 2 cents anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Such systems cannot be debugged effectively via blog.  The problem has to be isolated hands-on.  If the OP does not realize this, they should not be developing distributed systems:(

Close as 'too broad'.

Comment: If the answer was able to isolate and addresses the problem in question and becomes a useful resources to others, then it doesn't seem the question itself is too broad.  Should we be closing the question just because the asker added additional comments asking for more complete code?  If the answer was able **succinctly** addressed the problem, then the question was probably not too broad.  Let the asker be unhappy that the answer wasn't in the wanted format. The answer may still get upvotes if the community feels the answer addressed the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's unfair of the poster to expect code to be rewritten; and I write this as someone who has needed a lot of help recently, as I am finishing an interaction design program that expects you to create the product...and I ended up trying to teach myself Java/Android development over the past two months to get some good example.

I suspect many of the people asking for the code are like me, forced in a situation where you have to get a project done, and there is no one to help you at the university (my adviser knows nothing about Java/Android, and I could not identify anyone in my circle who did). Ignoring the plea will force the person to be creative, or just work through the example...I've never done the "please rewrite my code" plea, even though I am new to programming..I have either been creative (the thesis requires a demo..so, if I can't figure out a., how can I show how it would work if I could figure it out) or just tried some alternate way to setup the program/code to make it work.

I think becoming a programmer requires the frustration, pushing through...this site is just to give someone a direction in which to go, often, as the specific application/context is often too unique to provide a definitive answer...